# Given positive real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ with $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,\frac{1}{4+a}=1$, prove that $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,\frac{a}{4+a^2}\le1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, tangent-line-method

> Let $a, b, c, d, e$ be positive real numbers such that $$\dfrac{1}{4+a} + \dfrac{1}{4+b} +\dfrac{1}{4+c} +\dfrac{1}{4+d} +\dfrac{1}{4+e}  = 1.$$ Prove that $$\dfrac{a}{4+a^{2}} + \dfrac{b}{4+b^{2}} +\dfrac{c}{4+c^{2}} +\dfrac{d}{4+d^{2}} +\dfrac{e}{4+e^{2}}  \leq 1.$$

My question is how to prove this inequality by using AM-GM inequality?

My solution (using the Chebyshev inequality).

Since $\dfrac{1}{4+a}+\dfrac{1}{4+b}+\dfrac{1}{4+c}+\dfrac{1}{4+d}+\dfrac{1}{4+e} =1,$ we have

$$1 = \dfrac{1}{4+a}+\dfrac{1}{4+b}+\dfrac{1}{4+c}+\dfrac{1}{4+d}+\dfrac{1}{4+e} \geq \dfrac{a}{4+a^2}+\dfrac{b}{4+b^2}+\dfrac{c}{4+c^2}+\dfrac{d}{4+d^2}+\dfrac{e}{4+e^2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1-a}{(4+a)(4+a^2)}+\dfrac{1-b}{(4+b)(4+b^2)}+\dfrac{1-c}{(4+c)(4+c^2)}+\dfrac{1-d}{(4+d)(4+d^2)}+\dfrac{1-e}{(4+e)(4+e^2)} \geq 0.$$

Suppose that $a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq e$. Then, we get
$$\dfrac{1-a}{4+a} \leq \dfrac{1-b}{4+b} \leq \dfrac{1-c}{4+c} \leq \dfrac{1-d}{4+d} \leq \dfrac{1-e}{4+e}.$$
and $$\dfrac{1}{4+a^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{4+b^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{4+c^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{4+d^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{4+e^2}.$$

Applying the Chebyshev inequality, one gets
$$ \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1-a}{(4+a)(4+a^2)} \geq \dfrac{1}{5} \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1-a}{4+a}. \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{4+a^2} = \dfrac{1}{5}\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{4+a^2} \sum_{cyc} \left( \dfrac{5}{4+a}-1 \right)=0.$$

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Can you suggest to me? I have no idea to prove this inequality.

Comment: Can you show, how you proved this inequality without AM-GM?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I use the Chebyshev inequality to solve this problem. Please see my solution above.

Comment: @Batominovski can you quote what you mean by Chebyshev's inequality? because when I look online I find crazy stuff relating to probability theory. And can you say what you are applying the inequality to? I dont know if you mean the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, or if this is some other result. because where you say "applying the Chebyshev inequality", I have absolutely no idea what you are doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way.

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{4+a^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+3}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$1-\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+3}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{a}{2a+3}\right)\geq0$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1-a}{2a+3}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1-a}{2a+3}+5\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{4+a}\right)\right)\geq0$$  or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2}{(2a+3)(4+a)}\geq0.$$

Comment: In the last inequality, we replace "$(4+a)^2$" with "$2a+3$".

Comment: @Success It was typo. I fixed.

Comment: you say that by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{4+a^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+3}.$$, you havent said what set of numbers you are applying the AM-GM inequality to, please clarify. I presume firstly you mean that by AM-GM you get the inner term, $$\frac{a}{4+a^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+3}$$, but its not apparent how you got that from the AM-GM! it really isnt apparent to me and is under the category of "missing steps". Also that first step is a real rabbit pulled out of a hat! its not apparent what made you select out that very unusual inequality.

Comment: typo in earlier question, should say: I presume firstly you mean that by AM-GM you get the inner term, $$\frac{a}{4+a^2}\leq\frac{a}{2a+3}$$   I could show that by rearranging, but I dont know if that was intended.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that $$1-\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{4+a^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{a}{4+a^2}+3\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{4+a}\right)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3-a^2-a+1}{(4+a^2)(4+a)}\geq0.$$
Now, by AM-GM $$a^3+\frac{1}{2}\geq\frac{3}{2}a^2$$ and $$\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}\geq a,$$ which after summing gives $$a^3-a^2-a+1\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: what are you applying AM-GM to, to get $$a^3+\frac{1}{2}\geq\frac{3}{2}a^2$$? with the second inequality $$\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}\geq a,$$, I can see you are applying AM-GM to the 2 different means of $$a^2,1$$. But with the first inequality the means of $$2a^3,1$$ gives $$a^3+\frac{1}{2}\geq \sqrt{2a^3}$$ which isnt the inequality, so you are doing some hidden step which you havent explained.

Comment: ok, I think I have it now, it is AM-GM applied to $$a^3,a^3,1$$ to get $$\dfrac{1}{3}(a^3+a^3+1)>=\sqrt[3]{a^3a^31}$$ ie $$\dfrac{1}{3}(2a^3+1)>=a^2$$ thus $$a^3+1/2>=\dfrac{3}{2}a^2$$